# Copying cell range from a workbook sheet to another workbook sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have 3 workbooks, namely: A, B and C.

I'm coding a VBA macro inside A in order to copy cell range content of a particular sheet from B to C.

```
Dim wb_TC_PBS As Excel.Workbook
Dim wb_SPO_PBS As Excel.Workbook

Set wb_TC_PBS = Workbooks.Open("C:\temp\migration\B.xlsm")
Application.CutCopyMode = False
FinalRow = Sheets("TC_PBS").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Range("A5:EO" & FinalRow).Copy
```

I would like to understand if my approach is correct and how to continue pasting content on workbook C

Comment: After `Range("A5:EO" & FinalRow).Copy`  remove this line `Application.CutCopyMode = False` because it removes what you've just copied from the clipboard it's equivalent to pressing `ESC` key after you copy some range in excel. Then Activate and select the range and sheet where you want to paste.

Comment: thx, I need this command; because I've tried something like this, but doesn't work     wb_SPO_PBS.Sheets("Input").Offset(5).Insert Shift:=xlDown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here this might help

```
Dim a As Workbook,b As Workbook, c As Workbook, FinalRow As Long

Set a = ThisWorkbook
Set b = Workbooks.Open("C:\temp\migration\B.xlsm")
Set c = Workbooks.Open("C:\temp\migration\C.xlsm")

b.Activate
FinalRow = b.Sheets("TC_PBS").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
b.Sheets("TC_PBS").Range("A5:EO" & FinalRow).Copy
c.Activate
c.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").Select
c.Sheet1.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Comment: I received msg: "Object doesn't support this property or method" on Select method

Comment: thx now works, but only with sheet name: c.Sheets("Input").Activate